C++ (Template) Wrapper for Intel IPP functions
I would like to use Intel IPP (Integrated Performance Primitive) library functions sparingly in my C++ code. I could observe that, though these functions are C-style functions, there is a logical pattern in the function names that depends on the data type.
How can we write a C++ wrapper based on templates?
A simple example will be the FIR filter where we need to use "ippsFIRSR_32f" for "float" and "ippsFIRSR_64f" for "double" data types.
Is there any way to write a very generic C++ template wrapper for all IPP calls?

You could write a template wrapper, with if constexpr together with std::is_same that will dispatch to the relevant IPP function based on the parameter type. But I think it will only make the code more complicated to understand. Do you have a good reason to do it (over a direct usage of IPP functions) ? You mention you need to use IPP sparingly, which make an even stronger case to avoid the additional layer.

Thanks for your reply.  I would like to create wrapper functions/classes based on templates so that the people who use it need not worry about the underlying functions.

Posted an answer demonstrating how to do it with if constexpr and std::is_same.

If an answer solves your problem @Soo, you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer. You can also upvote any helpful answer(s) (voting and accepting is separate). See here: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

You can implement a template wrapper, that uses if constexpr with std::is_same to call the relevant IPP function based on the parameters type. Using if constexpr means choosing which function to call will be resolved at compile time, with on runtime overhead.
You can add static_asserts to check the validity of types during compilation.
As an example, let's take the following 2 functions you mentioned:
IppStatus ippsFIRSR_32f(const Ipp32f* pSrc, Ipp32f* pDst, int numIters, IppsFIRSpec_32f* pSpec, const Ipp32f* pDlySrc, Ipp32f* pDlyDst, Ipp8u* pBuf);

IppStatus ippsFIRSR_64f(const Ipp64f* pSrc, Ipp64f* pDst, int numIters, IppsFIRSpec_64f* pSpec, const Ipp64f* pDlySrc, Ipp64f* pDlyDst, Ipp8u* pBuf);

You can wrap them in the following way:
template <typename DATA, typename SPEC>
IppStatus ippsFIRSR_wrapper(const DATA* pSrc, DATA* pDst, int numIters, SPEC* pSpec, const DATA* pDlySrc, DATA* pDlyDst, Ipp8u* pBuf)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<DATA, Ipp32f> || std::is_same_v<DATA, Ipp64f>);
    // You can add more assertions regarding the SPEC type and its match to DATA type.

    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<DATA, Ipp32f>)
        return ippsFIRSR_32f(pSrc, pDst, numIters, pSpec, pDlySrc, pDlyDst, pBuf);
    else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<DATA, Ipp64f>)
        return ippsFIRSR_64f(pSrc, pDst, numIters, pSpec, pDlySrc, pDlyDst, pBuf);
    else
        return ippStsBadArgErr;
}

Usage example:
// All the variables below MUST be initialized:
Ipp32f * pSrc;           // = ...
Ipp32f * pDst;           // = ...
int numIters;            // = ...
IppsFIRSpec_32f * pSpec; // = ...
Ipp32f* pDlySrc;         // = ...
Ipp32f* pDlyDst;         // = ...
Ipp8u* pBuf;             // = ...

// Call the wrapper:
// (NOTE: the template parameter types are automatically infered)
IppStatus st = ippsFIRSR_wrapper(pSrc, pDst, numIters, pSpec, pDlySrc, pDlyDst, pBuf);

// Check st ...

Note that the wrapper adds some complication to your code, and so I would recommend it only if you have a good reason. By default I would simply use the IPP functions directly without the intermediate layer.

You don't need template, simple overload would do the stuff:
IppStatus ippsFIRSR(const Ipp32f* pSrc,
                    Ipp32f* pDst,
                    int numIters,
                    IppsFIRSpec_32f* pSpec,
                    const Ipp32f* pDlySrc,
                    Ipp32f* pDlyDst,
                    Ipp8u* pBuf)
{
    return ippsFIRSR_32f(pSrc, pDst, numIters, pSpec, pDlySrc, pDlyDst, pBuf);
}

IppStatus ippsFIRSR(const Ipp64f* pSrc,
                    Ipp64f* pDst,
                    int numIters,
                    IppsFIRSpec_64f* pSpec,
                    const Ipp64f* pDlySrc,
                    Ipp64f* pDlyDst,
                    Ipp8u* pBuf)
{
    return ippsFIRSR_64f(pSrc, pDst, numIters, pSpec, pDlySrc, pDlyDst, pBuf);
}

